# Write a book using Latex!

Tags: book-design

I want to write a physics book with the style like this. Can anyone help me!
I need two columns with different width in one page.
Thank for viewing!

[image]

Here is "theory part"
[image]

And "exercise part"
[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Please reduce your question to the very problem. Give us some minimal compilable code of your document and explain, what you have tried and where you are having problems. E.g. a two columns document as code together with the question: "How do I set the left column to one third of the text-width?". We like to help, but we do not want to set up a problem for you. If you really need only one page like this, you should insert everything in a table.

Comment: I recommend to start with the `tufte`-class. Have a look at [this page](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/)

Comment: @Sveinung: As in almost any of our encounters here, we have different opinions. You might vote for reopening (if not having done so)...

Comment: @Sveinung: As you can see: My name does not appear in the close - voter - list above...

Comment: I'm writing a physic book. I want to make it look like the picture above. For example, in one section, there are two parts. The first one is "theory part". In this part, I want it seperate into two column, one for main text and another one for side notes, pictures or tables. And second part is "exercise part". In this part, the page shoud be devide into two columns with the same width. My problem is "theory" part!

One more time. Thank everyone!!!

Comment: ChristianHupfer please forgive me because of my bad English.
LaRiFaRi thank you!
Sveinung Thanks for your suggestion. I've already seen the tufte class. And my question is: "How to make the main text in each page automatically places in the inner of the page (E.X main text is on the left of even page.

Comment: @ĐạiBàngHamHọc It would be helpful if you edited your question to include the information of your last two comments, then other people seeing the question wont have to search through the comments as well, to get all the information. If you have a specific document class that you want to use, please state this as well. By the way, `tufte-book` doesn't really have two columns, figures etc. can be placed in the margin, as in your screenshot. (ctd.)

Comment: Finally, it is generally best to ask questions about just one specific issue. E.g., your last question about having the larger outer margin (`\document[symmetric]{tufte-book}` if you're using that class) is very different from the question about getting two columns of the same width as textwidth+marginparwidth.

Comment: Since the question is on hold (or closed) it is impossible for me to answer it. As far as I know, the `tufte`-class is the nearest I am aware of a complete class with a layout similar to your request. If that class is not suitable, you have to start with another class, add packages and code until you have what you are searching for. I suggest starting either with `memoir`or `KOMAscript` (ùse `scrbook.cls`). `memoir`has better documentation, but KOMA-script`has some very nice and advance features. You will not be able to make such book without reading the documentation for the packages.

Comment: @Sveinung KOMAscript is my choice. It's easy to use and creates a beautiful document. Thank for your very useful help!